# Why does socket.io require a new listener

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

I know this ia probably a stupid question, but i sure hope i get the noob pass but I'm using the express framework with node js and mongo db. Why do you always have to create a new server in order for you to connect it from the client side.

```
1. server side:

var app = express();

var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8000);



2. Client side:

    var socket = io.connect('`http://localhost:8000`');
    socket.on('connect', function () {
      socket.emit('set nickname', confirm('Connected'));
    });
```

Normally i would use localhost:/3000 now in order for me to connect to the server i have to use localhost:/8000 isnt there a way to use the default 3000 but this always throw an err:

```
events.js:72
        throw er;
```

Regards

p.s i am very new to this and i am also reading tutorials but i cant seem to understand why this is please someone explain!

Comment: It is not clear if the failing code is the same exact code where 8000 is replaced with 3000 (which is no problem to me). Can you confirm ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you require somewhere in your code http, express ?
Maybe another app running on :8000 ?

Also, maybe missing some listeners:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.emit('connect');
});
```